# Force user to confirm terms and conditions (once/every time) without getting them crazy?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm having a slightly weird requirement for an Intranet Sharepoint 2010 server platform. User shall be forced to confirm their specific terms+conditions before they use the platform.

Details:

- Sign on to Sharepoint automatically via Windows/AD login.
- Authentification gateway (UAG) for external users is planned (might be used for internal users, too)
- Needs differentiation between Admin group and "normal users", as admins shall confirm *every* time they log on, normal users only once/first time
- only "no code" solutions, Sharepoint Designer would be ok though. Third-party-solutions, too ;-)

The problem I see is that I need to identify users and user groups before they are logged on to Sharepoint. If I allow them to log on, I need to redirect them to the confirmation page depending from their status (admin/user/confirmed/new) - which would need some programming, I suppose.

I'm not very deep into complex workflows or Infopath to develop an idea with them. We used heavy XSLT-coding (show content depending on user group, filter by AD attributes, using Webservices etc., ) in a different SP 2007 project before, but as this is almost unmaintainable and thus not sustainable, I'd prefer to find something different.

One more idea would be to manipulate the portal page of the UAG with some confirmation link, not sure this was done before or would be something that is supported.

Any hint or idea would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Jasper

Answer (score 2):

Permanent method:

For this, create a user profile field that stores if they have accepted or not. This field should be not visible to editing, or on the user profile but it should be set to NOT read only so that you can update it via code.

Then create a user control and add it to the head of your master page which checks this value.

If the value has not been set and they aren't already on the T&Cs page then redirect to the T&Cs, they accept and set the user profile field.

This won't redirect again.

User control to read user profile manager to get the user data and redirect if required.

ascx control built in Visual Studio

Utilising:

```
UserProfileManager
SPUtility.Redirect
```

A layout page deployed to _layouts which again utilises the above.

You can also flip that on it's head and do it as a session cookie if you want it just for that session.

Comment: Perfect solution.

Comment: thanks! just to make clear: that would be a coded solution, right? Needs deployment etc... Not sure we can use it then. However, looks like a nice approach.

Comment: There is only a coded solution really for this, unless you write it all client side in JavaScript and use designer to add it to the master page, then it becomes a code-ish solution.

Comment: I hate these undeployable Javascript solutions, too - anyway we don't have the .NET deployment infrastructure here. However to do it e.g. with XSLT + Webservices (get permission group, show content dependent on list values combined with user name + group) requires an enterprise license which is not present neither here. *sigh* - However: your answers were clear and helpful, thanks for that!

Comment: When you are restricted by the options allowed, there comes a point where you have to say you can't have this unless you untie my hands. Good luck!